# Remove multiple licenses via Azure AD v2 powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I want to remove multiple licenses using PowerShell. Actually I able to remove single licence like below. But How do I remove multiple licenses?

```
$AzureUser = Get-AzureAdUser -ObjectId $ADuser.UserPrincipalName

$License = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicense

$License.SkuId = "6fd2c87f-b296-42f0-b197-1e91e994b900"   #6fd2c87f-b296-42f0-b197-1e91e994b900 Office 365 E3

$LicensesToAssign = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicenses

$LicensesToAssign.AddLicenses = @()
$LicensesToAssign.RemoveLicenses = $License.SkuId

Set-AzureADUserLicense -ObjectId $AzureUser.ObjectId -AssignedLicenses $LicensesToAssign
```

Comment: Maybe we can use Azure AD v1 powershell to do it, please check my answer, please let me know if you need more help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But How do I remove multiple licenses?

There is a easy way to achieve this, we can use MSOL powershell (Azure AD v1) to do it:

We can use this script to list all licences assigned to this account:

```
$UPN = jasontest1@tech1108.com
$a = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UPN
$c = $a.Licenses.accountskuid
```

Then we can use `foreach` to remove all licences:

```
foreach ( $d in $c ){ Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $UPN -RemoveLicenses $d }
```

Here is the information about `-RemoveLicenses`, please refer to this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771774.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

By the way, if you want to install MSOL powershell on your PC, we can use this command to install it: `install-module msonline`.

---

Update:

We can use this script to remove licenses from one account(Azure AD PowerShell V2).

```
$a = get-azureaduser -ObjectId "4xxxxxxx0"
$skuids = $a.AssignedLicenses.skuid
$License = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicense
$LicensesToAssign = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicenses
$LicensesToAssign.AddLicenses = @()
foreach($skuid in $skuids){$License.SkuId = $skuid; $LicensesToAssign.RemoveLicenses = $License.SkuId; Set-AzureADUserLicense -ObjectId "user-object-id" -AssignedLicenses $LicensesToAssign}
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to do it via azure ad v2

Comment: Is this cmdlet still valid to remove or add the license?